# Set gradient for background actionbar

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, gradient

I try set gradient for background actionbar but background not match parent actionbar

Here is code gradient_actionbar

```
<gradient
    android:angle="360"
    android:centerColor="@color/color2"
    android:endColor="@color/color3"
    android:startColor="@color/color1"
    android:type="linear"
     />

<corners
    android:radius="0dp"/>
```

Here is code actionbar_layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_actionbar"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is code MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DrawerLayout drawer;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
Toolbar toolbar;
TextView tvName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    tvName = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_layout);
}
```

[This layout when run application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKvEu.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a GradientDrawable in res/drawable/mygradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:useLevel="false" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="360"
        android:centerColor="@color/color2"
        android:endColor="@color/color3"
        android:startColor="@color/color1"
        android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

Then set it to action bar in your Activity's onCreate():

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();    
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mygradient));
```

For support v7 library (your case):

```
// make sure to import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();        
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mygradient));
```